# Нужно вставить 2 картинки в input. Одну вставил а как в другую?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, знаю как в input добавить одно изображение:

```
<input type=text style="background: url(https://blog.ivru.net/folder.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 4px;padding-left: 44px;" value="Тестовое поле ввода">
```

Только мне нужно 2 изображения. Одно слева другое справа. Как это сделать? Можно ли не использовать span а обойтись только атрибутом style тега input?

Answer (score 3):

Сделать можно почти всё - было бы желание ;-)

```html
<input type="text" style="
  background-image: url(https://blog.ivru.net/folder.png), url(https://blog.ivru.net/folder.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: center left .5em, center right .5em;
  background-size: auto 100%, auto 100%;
  padding: .5em 3em;
" value="Тестовое поле ввода">
```